# Reload data in programmatically created tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have looked at a number of other SO questions related to this question and have not found one dealing with my specific situation.  I create a variable number of tableViews programmatically in one method. At a later point, I would like to reload the data in any one of the tableViews in another method. I would like to use...

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

to reload the data in a specific tableView.  The problem I am having is accessing the tableView that was created programmatically at a later point.  My thought is to set a unique tag for each tableView as it is created.

So here is my question.  Is it possible to create and initialize a tableView by referring to an existing tableView's tag.  For instance, with a UIView it is possible to...

```
UIView *notATableView = [[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:1];
```

which would allow me to modify the view whose tag was equal to 1.  Does a similar possibility exist for tableViews?

Comment: You just use instance variables or properties --[self.tableView1 reloadData] or [self.tableView2 reloadData]

Comment: I agree with rdelmar - Why bother setting tags when you can assign the created tableviews to properties. Far more maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the tag on your table view when you create it and retrieve the table view later using `viewWithTag`.

```
// Assuming you've added the table view as a subview to the current view controller
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

However, you're not re-allocating it. You're just getting a pointer to it.

Then, just reload the data or do whatever:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling casting would be part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just refer to the UITableViews by their property names.

```
[self.thisTableView reloadData];
[self.thatTableView reloadData];
```

No tags needed!

You can also use the property names for IF checking in your UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods

```
if(tableView == self.thisTableView){
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Things like `self.thisTableView` are more often referred to as *properties* or *instance variables*.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use tags like this (in general I try to stay away from them altogether). Store the created tableviews in instance variables, or in an array.

Comment: I really like this idea. It had not crossed my mind. Why do you stay tend to stay away from tags?

Comment: Tags are non unique. I've been bit by this in reality: a tableviewcell going into edit mode adds a bunch of subviews which have tag ids, they collided with the ones I picked. That was a fun night of debugging. Searching a subview tree for tags is slow, especially if the tree has many nodes. None of these problems apply to just storing the object pointers!

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

```
tablesArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Make `tablesArray` globally. Then add each `tableView's` instance it.

```
[tablesArray addObject:tbl1];
[tablesArray addObject:tbl2];
```

Now you can get them in easy way.

```
UITableView *tbl1 = (UITableView *)[tablesArray objectAtIndex:0];
[tbl1 reloadData];
```

**2.**

You can create `@property` for each `tableView` and can compare them directly.

**3.**

As you are asking about tag so yes you can use tags too.

```
[tableView1 setTag:1];
[self.view addSubview:tableView1];
// how to get
UITableView *tableView1 = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```